# Regex replace a character inside

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How do I write a regular expression in javascript that replaces everything with a certain chararacter inside "url()"?

Example string

```
"blabla url(hello;you);"
```

I want to replace the ";"-sign inside url() to something else to like

```
"blabla url(hello[]you);"
```

Comment: Look like javascipt needs lookbehinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "blabla url(hello;you;cutie);";
str = str.replace( /url\(([^)]+)\)/g, function(url){
  return url.replace( /;/g, '[]' );
});
// "blabla url(hello[]you[]cutie);"
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm maybe something like this:

```
var result = "blabla url(hello;you)".replace(/url\(([^)]*)\)/, function(_, url) {
  return "url(" + url.replace(/;/g, "[]") + ")";
});
```

I used two calls to ".replace()" which *might* not be necessary but it made it easier for me to think about. The outer one isolates the "url()" contents, and then the inner replace fixes the semicolons.

Comment: No need to reconstruct the URL, since it doesn't have any semicolons on it, it won't be affected by the inner replace.

Comment: It won't be replaced by the *inner* replace, but the outer one will replace the entire matched string.

Answer (score 0):

regEx seems a bit heavy. split-join is probably faster in most browsers.

```
var result = "blabla url(hello;you)".split(';').join('[]');
```

For regEx required I guess I'd do:

```
var result = "blabla url(hello;you)".replace(/;/,'[]');
```

Comment: oops. Didn't read question carefully enough. Not sure it's doable in one replace without lookbehinds. If it's only one semi between the parens you're worried about, you could use capturing.